# recognizing wood -- good database

Tags: wood-species

My wife bought some 3 cubic meters of wood from the construction site two streets away (unfortunately they had to fall a few trees). The sort was unknown, as she saw it first when it was already cut to logs. Because of characteristic bark, we could recognize a few as locust, other - no clue. We live in Germany, so there is a good chance that these were European trees. One of this has pretty nice colouration in crosscut and also is quite hard (see pictures, diameter ~25cm/10").

I would be very happy if anybody could name it, but even more if you could share a link to a database with good quality pictures. I know only about [www.wood-database.com](http://www.wood-database.com) but unfortunately there are mostly pictures of cut timber (in some cases only burl) but none of cross-sections.

[image: cross-section]
[image: bark]

*p.s.* google-search after wood cross-section is a nightmare. Most of the pictures have wrong labels.

Comment: Closing this as a dupe of another question that already has some good answers. Your local library may also have some wood identification books on-hand.

Comment: We can't do wood IDs here, your best bet is to ask this on a woodworking forum (this is a question-and-answer venue, not a conventional discussion forum) and possibly best asked on one based on the Continent rather than one of the British ones. A firm ID may be difficult as one of the key identifiers is gone — the leaves. The wood itself, and the bark, can be surprisingly unhelpful LOL!

Comment: One piece of advice that's rather urgent, if you haven't already done so you must seal the ends to slow water loss through the end grain or you'll lose a lot of the usable wood to cracks which as you can see have already started to form. The best thing for this is melted wax. If you can't use that then a few heavy coats of varnish would be your best option.